# Can a greasable U-Joint showing stiffness be "saved" by greasing

Tags: grease, drive-shaft, u-joint

I recently pulled the driveshaft off my 1986 Dodge B250 van, expecting to replace one or both universal joints.  I was surprised to see they both have zerks, so can be serviced (sure wish I'd noticed sooner).

The rear U-joint moves freely in all directions and seems fine, the front joint only moves freely in one direction, the other axis has definite resistance, but can still be moved by hand.

There is no play or looseness, just stiffness on one axis.

My general understanding is that if a U-joint is showing signs of wear, like not moving freely, it should be replaced. However, if I grease this joint and it begins to move freely, is it considered it still good?

Comment: The zerks may be used for initial manufacturing ; As I remember ,I could not find a tip that could fit onto the U joint zerks. On the other hand it is relatively easy nuts and bolts to remove , clean, examine and reinstall the U joints .Or replace them as the seals should be bad after  35 years.

Comment: Replacing them on age alone is definitely a consideration, particularly after I went to the trouble of getting the shaft off, it's not like they are an expensive part. However, I'm pretty sure these aren't the originals, I'll probably grease the rear and swap the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: NO

By the time there is looseness or roughness the damage is already done.  The only thing left is eventual failure of the joint.  As long as you are prepared to deal with that happening at the most inconvenient time (think late at night, it's raining, you're running late, etc.) then by all means, grease it and keep driving.

If that's not OK with you, then you should replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you saying you *don't* want to be crawling under a van on the side of a dark highway in the pouring rain?  'cause I feel like this could go either way.... I'm trying to save 26 bucks here!    In all seriousness though, yeah, thanks, this is what I figured, but I was curious.

Comment: Some folks may be into that but I'm not...

Comment: After removing the U-joint and looking under the caps there were visible ribs on three of the four ends, it was definitely shot, glad I didn't waste any time trying to grease it.

Answer (score 1):

My 4x4 had 4 of those uj's and I used to grease them weekly and always after they were immersed in water.

They lasted a lot longer than if I practiced "fit & Forget"...

However, I was also skilled at using the tow bar and a hydraulic jack for changing them.

Any roughness then replace is my advice.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, that greasing these is for prevention, once it's showing signs of being under greased like this one is, the damage is done. Feel like you are backing that position up here.